# Custom Modules Help

Tags: 7, hooks

First of all I am a Drupal beginner.

I need to implement a reward points functionality on a Drupal 7 website. A user is given points by performing certain actions such as user registration, when the user makes a booking through the system or when the user refers the website to other friends.

My question is when the administrator wants to know what are the users' reward points. How can I do this? Is it through a custom module and using a costume template (tpl.php)?

Thanks.

Comment: How do you assign this points?

Comment: Are you saying that points should be awarded automatically when a user registers, etc?

Comment: @EmmyS. Thanks. Yes points are awarded automaticanlly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're saying that the points are awarded automatically when a user registers, creates a node, etc., rather than being assigned by an administrator, you might want to look at the [UserPoints](http://drupal.org/project/userpoints) module. It assigns points based on certain actions. There's a helper module called [UserPoints Contrib](http://drupal.org/project/userpoints_contrib), which extends UserPoints to many more actions.

Comment: Thanks Emmy that is exactly what I needed. I'll have a look.